# How to send a second (distinct) model instance to a template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Problem - I am displaying a form allowing a user to add a comment regarding an existing post.  I also want to display the existing post (instance) on this same page (rendered template).  The model for the template is the one accepting the comment (distinct from the post).  How do I pass a model instance for the post data to the template so I can display the post too?

Note - I also need the post instance because in order to store the comment in the database, it needs to be linked to the specific post id.

This is probably easy and I'm missing something obvious - pointers to the right documentation welcome.  I am just learning Django so I'm still learning my way around.

Details:

I have my model as follows (models.py):

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(
        PostType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='posts',
        default=1
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='posts'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments',
    )
    body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.body[:75]}...'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.post.id)])
```

I have my URL routing in urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/new/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_new'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    ...
]
```

I have my view (views.py):

```py
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    fields = ['body']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And finally my template (comment_new.html):

```html
    <div class="card post-entry">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ post.title }}</span>
        <span class="m-3">&middot;</span>
        <span class="text-muted">{{ post.type }} by {{ post.author }} - {{ post.created|naturaltime }}</span>
        {{ post.body }}
    </div>

    <hr>
    <h2>New Comment</h2>
    <hr>

    <div class="post-entry-comment">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for get_context_data [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).  That's an easy way to pass in additional data to a class based template.